# Hadoop: ClassNotFound Exception: WordCount$Map

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I am using hadoop version hadoop-0.20.205.0 for testing a WordCount example. I built the Jar file and I tried to run it using the following command:

```
hadoop Jar myJar.jar wordCount input output
```

However I am getting this exception: Seems that mapper and reducer have been started since as you can see in the log there is "map 0% reduce 0%".

```
15/08/10 11:53:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/08/10 11:53:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
15/08/10 11:53:27 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/08/10 11:53:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201508100953_0021
15/08/10 11:53:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/08/10 11:53:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201508100953_0021_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:864)
    ... 8 more

15/08/10 11:53:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201508100953_0021_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:864)
    ... 8 more

15/08/10 11:53:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201508100953_0021_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:864)
    ... 8 more

15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201508100953_0021
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=25289
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
15/08/10 11:54:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1

real    0m42.316s
user    0m0.980s
sys 0m2.828s
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: when you run hadoop, try to change wordCount to WordCount 
does it make any difference?

Comment: Well, actually I run it using WordCount which exactly the same name as the main class.

Comment: you also do jar instead of Jar ?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference. You can try both

Comment: try to run without      conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));